# Android int/double calculation randomly overflow

Tags: android

```
    int n1 = 65535;
    int n2 = 1659;
    int fs1 = 144000;
    int fs2 = 7056000;
    int dfrq = 44100;
    int delay = (int) ((double) n1 / 2 / ((double) fs1 / dfrq) + (double) n2 / 2 / ((double) fs2 / dfrq));
```

The above calculation result give me randomly values, sometimes it's correct delay= 10040, but sometimes the delay= 2147483647, which is 0b1111111111111111111111111111111 in binary, it's overflow.

The problem is why on android, this calculation gives two different results, and randomly.

My temp solution is:

```
    double s1 = 1f * n1 / 2;
    double s2 = 1f * fs1 / dfrq;
    double s3 = 1f * n2 / 2;
    double s4 = 1f * fs2 / dfrq;
    L.d(TAG, "s1:" + s1 + " s2:" + s2 + " s3:" + s3 + " s4:" + s4);

    int delay = (int) (s1 / s2 + s3 / s4);
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate the random number using Java Code ??

Comment: no, this is calcaultation, i expect the result 10040, but sometimes, give me 2147483647.

Comment: I can run your code snippet in a loop 1000 times in my sample Android app and it always returns 10040.  What happens if you declare each of those variables final in your app?  In other words, are you sure there isn't something somewhere else that is modifying the values after the fact?

Comment: Try rebuilding your project

Comment: @MichaelKrause  This is single thread.  I think it's related to multiple devide operator.